# Convert xml to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel

As I am trying to convert xml file to excel.

I am able to do this with `.xls` file extensions only. When I try to convert xml file to excel with `.xlsx` extension I am able to create the excel file, but am unable to open it.

When I attempt to open the created excel file I receive the following Error message:

> Excel cannot open the file 'Request.xlsx'because the file format or
>   the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Here is my code:

```cs
dt = project2.ConvertXMLToDataSet(xmlString);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

        string filename = xmlfileName + ".xlsx";
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
        DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
        dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
        dgGrid.DataBind();
        dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
                              "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
        Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found two older post here on stackoverflow. I hope one of them will help:

- [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)
- [What is the best way to store XML data in an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443026/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-xml-data-in-an-excel-file)

Comment: Thanks for the above links.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just dump datagrid into response and expect it to be picked up by Excel. You need to convert data in proper format. I find [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) the most appropriate tool to do that. It is quite a bit of extra work, but you'll be able to do what you need to do and you'll have much more control over the resulting Excel file.