# How do I add a custom XML to an open Excel 2007 workbook using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, excel-2007, excel-interop

I'm trying to add a custom XML to an open Excel 2007 workbook using C#. I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as an interface. I've discovered there's a CustomXMLPart class but I can't figure out how to use it.
Initially I expected the code to be something simple like:

> CustomXMLPart myXMLPart = new CustomXMLPart(xmlString);
>
> myWorkBook.XMLCustomParts.Add(myXMLPart);

but that isn't close to working.

I've tried finding examples online but they are bafflingly complex talking about Packages, Addins, OpenXML, VSTO streams etc. I've unzipped a suitable workbook (xlsx) and found it has docProps/custom.xml element.

I just want to add a similar custom.xml to a new workbook (2007) before saving it. Is this possible? Please note I can't install any additional packages or libraries.

Edit: I've made a tiny bit more progress investigating this issue. I am confident I have the correct Office reference (Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library under COM) and Excel interop reference (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel under GAC).

The declaration

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts myCustomXMLParts;
```

compiles, however

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts myCustomXMLParts =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts;
```

results in the error message: Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts' to 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts.

When I hover over the Excel CustomXMLParts property it claims to return a CustomXMLParts object which is in some sense, a Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts object but not quite the same as in the Office assembly. So there's clearly some incompatability here but I can't resolve it. I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007 (12.0.6612.1000) and Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies (12.0.4518.1014) installed.

Edit:
I am fairly certain that it's the Office DLL that's the problem. On Add-Reference I see "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" and can add it without any error. It appears as simply "Office" under References. However it seems to be invisible to the compiler while still claims Microsoft.Office.Core is defined in an assembly that is not referenced and specifies assembly 'office', Version=12.0.0.0.

My Office reference is linked to MSO.DLL under Microsoft Shared/OFFICE12 and has Major Version 2 Minor Version 4 under Properties. Does this matter? Or is the error message just indicating it isn't processing this referenced for some reason?

Edit: Adding the COM object "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" definitely seems to be the problem. From other forum posts I've discovered that other people see a reference of "Microsoft.Office.Core" appear but I only see "Office". I've tried editing the .csproj file directly and that does give a "Microsoft.Office.Core" but it still doesn't work. The only conclusion I can really make is that my MSO.DLL for Office 12 Professional Plus (version (12.0.6612.1000) doesn't actually contain Microsoft.Office.Core assemblies, or at any rate doesn't expose them properly.

Comment: What kind of application is this?  Excel automation might not be the right way to go about this depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Hey there, I am interested to see how you're going, did my answer help? If you need any extra help or have any concerns then let me know. I did put in several hours troubleshooting it myself. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - see below. Basically it's this wretched MSO.DLL

Comment: You do have Visual Studio now yeah? You downloaded and tried my solution? If anything.. this question should have yielded... it is YOU having a copy of Visual Studio installed? I cant believe you even bothered to write a solution using purely JUST the csc.exe and Office interops....

Answer (score 3):

The [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608627.aspx) give an example using VSTO and I've adapted this to work with a Winform application.

The trick (in this situation) is to reference the PIA **see the tooltip path of the Excel Reference in the screenshot below**. NOTE: I didn't use the .Net or COM reference tabs, I had to "Browse" for the Excel DLL.

---

Below is the Winform Code of a working example using the Excel PIA (also version 12.0.4518.1014). See screenshot for more detailed info of the Book1.xlsx renamed to a zip and extracted after I ran the code, along with the resulting *item1.xml* file in the *CustomXML* folder:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\test\Book1.xlsx";
    var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);

    string xmlString =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
    "<employees xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples\">" +
        "<employee>" +
            "<name>Karina Leal</name>" +
            "<hireDate>1999-04-01</hireDate>" +
            "<title>Manager</title>" +
        "</employee>" +
    "</employees>";

    wb.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString, Type.Missing);
    wb.Save();
}
```

Large view of screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Qhm.png

[image]

If you want to fetch customXML from a Workbook see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488072/495455.

---

**EDIT:**

I also have *Microsoft.Office.Core* ActiveX referenced from the GAC: `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll` and  *Microsoft VBIDE.Interop* from the GAC as well `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll`.

Here is my project, please try it out and hopefully you can see whats missing from your solution vs my one that works: http://JeremyThompson.Net/Rocks/OfficeExcelCustomXML.zip

**Please note the zip contains the GAC DLLs in the Bin\Debug folder.**

Comment: Thanks, although I had seen this already. When I add a reference (Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library under the COM tab, pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\MSO.DLL) I see "Office" appearing. However I believe other people get Microsoft.Office.Core. This Office is not properly exporting its members. When I try to build I get ' Error CS0012: The type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLParts' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio installed which is why I installed the appropriate Interop PIAs directly from a Microsoft download (I believe this worked fine) and the Microsoft Object Library from the Office installation - which doesn't work. Unfortunately I am at work and can't install your solution. However in any case you aren't getting my problem because you have the Office.DLL in the GAC. I will investigate this option.

Comment: I've given up now. I tried using gacutil to add the assemblies to the GAC but it threw errors. I don't know what it is about my setup (Office Pro but no Visual Studio) that makes the MSO.DLL simply not export the Microsoft.Office.Core classes.

Comment: Suggest you install Visual Studio, dont make stuff harder on yourself. And to the downvoter out there, care to explain?

Comment: I'm at work. I can't install anything. Visual Studio costs £2K/year or something. I can't get any budget. No I didn't downvote you.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is more than enough to get your work done, and it's free...

Comment: Do you know how to modify existing Custom XML parts in Excel? If you do please help. I have posted a question under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252524/how-to-modify-custom-xml-parts-in-excel-2010-2013

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be even more suitable for you to completly abandon the way via excel automation. Probably it would be enough to open the excel file via `System.IO.Packaging Namespace`. Here you can find a complete sample: [Add Custom XML Parts to Documents Without Starting Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608597(v=vs.90).aspx)

In contrast to the other posted answers this solution does not need any references to the Office PIAs. You just need to add a reference to `WindowsBase`, which is included in .NET. It can even handle other OpenXML document formats like docx, pptx...

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is wanting to add Custom XML to an Excel sheet that I cam creating programatically. Not running Excel somewhat defeats that.

Comment: That is exactly what the provided sample does!

Answer (score 0):

In you second snippet, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts is a type, you can not assign it to variable myCustomXMLParts. You would have to have

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = <some appropriate constructor>;
...
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts myParts = myWorkbook.CustomXMLParts;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a type, it's a property. Its return type is Microsoft.Office.Core.XMLParts - the type that can't be found in the Office MSO.DLL.

Comment: @TheMathemagician  **IT'S A TYPE**! You seem to be confused because  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts` [is a property on an `_Workbook` **Interface**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook_properties.aspx). In easy words; to make use of that property **you need to instantiate an object of `Workbook` type** as shown above in the answer.

Comment: scoutcat said "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts is a type". I said "No it's a property". You say I'm confused and it's a type and "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.CustomXMLParts is a property". Perhaps it's not me who's confused?

Comment: @It'sbeenapleasure Sorry if appeared ungrateful but yes, I know, I already have an instance of Workbook. The problem isn't where you think it is. It's not having the Microsoft.Office.Core classes loaded.