# How to modify Custom XML parts in Excel 2010/2013

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I am trying to figure out how to modify custom XML parts previusly saved in Excel. All the web resources I have found so far explain how to add custom XML parts in Excel. This I already know. But I want to modify existing parts.

The API seems to have only Add method. If Add method is called again it adds additional XML parts.

I use the following code to save my custom XML

```
XNamespace NS = "http://schema.blabla.com";
var xDoc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"),
            new XComment("Custom XML Parts demo"),
            new XElement(NS + "demo",
                new XElement(NS + "config",
                    new XElement(NS + "property",
                        new XAttribute("value", "myVlaue",                  
                        new XAttribute("key", "myKey"))))));

Office.CustomXMLPart customXMLPart = workbook.CustomXMLParts.Add(xDoc.ToString(), System.Type.Missing);
```

I use the following code to retrieve my custom XML

```
var retrievedXMLParts = workbook.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace(NS.NamespaceName);
//FirstOrDefault always returns first saved data, LastOrDefault needs to be called to get the latest            
//var customXMLPart = retrievedXMLParts.Cast<CustomXMLPart>().FirstOrDefault();
var customXMLPart = retrievedXMLParts.Cast<CustomXMLPart>().LastOrDefault();
var propertiesXML = customXMLPart != null ? customXMLPart.XML : String.Empty;
```

What I would like to achieve is to check if a custom XML exists update its content instead off adding it as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a solution but it involves iterating through all the custom XML parts, deleting the one you want to update and then add again:

```
IEnumerator e = workbook.CustomXMLParts.GetEnumerator();
CustomXMLPart p;
while (e.MoveNext())
{
    p = (CustomXMLPart) e.Current;
    //p.BuiltIn will be true for internal buildin excel parts 
    if (p != null && !p.BuiltIn && p.NamespaceURI == NS.NamespaceName)
        p.Delete();
}
```

Comment: This is what I would have suggested